# Running R on Windows and trying to access Linux files

Tags: r, linux, shared-directory

I am running R in Windows in my laptop and I also have a Linux server account. I am able to in Windows see the shared folder between the Windows and the Linux. The shared folder file address is like this:

```
file://name1/name2/home/user/project.
```

I would like to in Windows access the data files generated from my scripts in Linux. The question is how to access the data file in the shared folder:

```
file://name1/name2/home/user/project/data.rds
```

I tried these, but all failed.

```
data = readRDS("file://name1/name2/home/user/project/data.rds")
data = readRDS("file://name1//name2//home//user//project//data.rds")
data = readRDS(url("file://name1/name2/home/user/project/data.rds"))
data = readRDS("file:\\\name1\\\name2\\\home\\\user\\\project\\\data.rds")
data = readRDS("\\\name1\\\name2\\\home\\\user\\\project\\\data.rds")
data = readRDS("name1\\\name2\\\home\\\user\\\project\\\data.rds")
```

Comment: Sorry I don't actually know R, but if it uses \ as an escape character in strings like most languages, then to produce a Windows network path \\host\share\path you would want 4 at the start and 2 in the middle, like "\\\\host\\share\\path", instead of the three you have there.
If R does need 3 to make one backslash, then you would need 6 at the start.

Comment: It works. Thank you @Harun. I will make your comment the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the suggestion from @Harun, this line works:

```
data = readRDS("\\\\name1\\name2\\home\\user\\Project\\data.rds")
```